# Linking multiple Firebase project to single Ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a simple application with Ionic 3, already linked to his Firebase project, which has to manage a Firestore database from another Firebase project.

The question is: there's a way to link multiple firebase project with Ionic 3?

I'm using angularfire2 and I have already read the official Firebase Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application

But I can't understand how to do it with Ionic 3

Answer (score 1):

The docs are very clear on what to do. Example:

```
const firstAppConfig = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};

const firstFirebase = firebase.initializeApp(firstAppConfig, "first")

const secondAppConfig = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};

const secondFirebase = firebase.initializeApp(secondAppConfig, "second")

const thirdAppConfig = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};

const thirdFirebase = firebase.initializeApp(thirdAppConfig, "third")
```